# Implement hashCode and lazy-loading

Tags: java, hibernate, equals, hashcode

This has been discussed a lot (e. g. [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode?_sscc=t) and [there](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=53)) and for me it sounds useful to use "business" keys when implementing the hashCode-method for Hibernate entities like:

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    ...
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //Calculate on base of username
    }
}
```

This is better then using the ID in cases when the ID is generated by hibernate (it will be null for new entities).

What if an entity consists out of "virtual" lazy loaded properties only?
I could calculate the hashCode based on them and did it so far. Now I ran into the problem that when `hashCode()` is called, the session is closed and so the lazy loaded properties can't be accessed anymore. What to do in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

By default, if I were doing a code review of an entity, I would require the programmer to make `equals()` and `hashcode()` not depend on lazily loaded properties. It feels like a failure of abstraction to have `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods success or failure depend on hibernate's session state. After all, it is not a clean object if its business key is not available no more than if the primary key is not available.

I would suggest eagerly fetching the relevant properties. In some rare cases, you could make use of the `@Formula` hibernate annotation to get the necessary fields as derived properties to calculate `equals` and `hashcode`.